# Mongo in JPA presistance

Tags: mongodb, jpa, ejb-3.0, java-ee-7, hibernate-ogm

I am trying to connect mongo in Java EE7 with persistence, but I am not able to deploy the application in glassfish getting below error please help us to resolve the issue

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit name="MONGO" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

    <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
       <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider"/>
       <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="testDB"/>
     <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
     <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port" value="27017"/>
   </properties>
```

Getting Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/query/spi/NativeQueryInterpreter
at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmSessionFactoryServiceInitiators.<clinit>(OgmSessionFactoryServiceInitiators.java:25)
at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmSessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.createServiceBindings(OgmSessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:41)
```

Comment: NativeQueryInterpreter does not exist in Hibernate 4.2 How did you deploy hibernate in GlassFish? GlassFish uses EclipseLink by default

Comment: Then please tell us which version we need to use @SimonMartinelli

Comment: The most recent version is 5.4.1.Final